# A loop in a loop to fill an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, open-flash-chart

I am building a time registration program. Users can work on a project, and I want to display in a chart how many hours each user worked on a project, let's say, each month.  The chart plugin works like this:

```
first_serie = OpenFlashChartLazy::Serie.new(
[["2008-1",100],["2008-2",120],["2008-3",130]],
{:title=>"name_of_user1",:start_date=>Time.mktime(2008,1,1),:items=>8})
```

This adds a new line in the graph.

My question is how can I loop through all my users and for each fill a new series with data from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow up to Pesto would be nicer to use inject.

```
@series = User.all.inject([]) do |mem, user|
  mem << OpenFlashChartLazy::Serie.new(user.foo, user.bar, user.foobarbob)
end
```

Same code, just doesnt have a @series = []

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea how you generate all the data for Serie.new, but you can get started using this:

```
@series = []
users = User.find(:all)
users.each do |user|
  @series << OpenFlashChartLazy::Serie.new(blah, blah, blah)
end
```

This will add all of the added Serie objects to an array.

Comment: Thank you very much for insight this makes things clear...



@series.each do |serie|
      bar_graph.add_serie(serie)
end